# How to buffer results from a webpage to another?

Tags: html, flask

I am using flask for my website.
I want to submit data using a form from my website to another website and then format the results page (an html page) before displaying it on the browser on my website.

After the form is submitted, the browser is directed to results page of that (another) website. Can I redirect again it to my site?
How to process the results page(call its html content as a string in code) ?

Comment: I need this process (submitting form-> getting results from another webpage -> formatting page on my website) to be automatic i.e., no interactions from user.

Comment: Also that (another) website takes time to process form ~ 90 seconds and it varies depending upon input. While the form is being processed it shows an intermediate WAIT page. I don't want show it either. I want to show my wait page, if possible

Answer (score 0):

Sounds the process like this: user input the data -> your website get the data and post it to another website -> the website return a worked data -> your website receive this data, parse it and display it. I don't know you are familiar with API or not. If you are familiar with it you should know the process is just like using API. You just need to put all the process in a view and `add_url_rule` for it.